# image doesn't show up on canvas output

Tags: python, image, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to simply get some image on canvas, but even though I don't get any errors, my canvas stays white, no picture shows up. I know it will be some stupid misteak, but I can't find it.

```
def obrazek():
    mesic = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="moon-0.gif")
    canvas.create_image(700, 500, image = mesic)

rodic = tkinter.Tk()
rodic.title(u"Slunce a Měsíc")
rodic.geometry("+1000+300")
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(rodic, width=1400, height=800,)
canvas.pack()
obrazek()
tkinter.mainloop()
```

Output is whitescreen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a reference to the image by returning from the function

Then call `pack()` after the function `obrazek`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The `canvas.pack()` doesn't seem to work, but I accidentally found out, that if I write `global mesic` it works perfectly.